# Oracle creating Database link

Tags: database, oracle, express

I am using Oracle 11g express edition.
I have created tables, stored procedures and it works fine.
I have my user "System" with password "xyz" (main user  during installation).

Then i have created two databases "abc" and "pqr" with same user.

I wanted to create database link from abc to pqr.

```
create database link testlink
connect to pqr identified by xyz
 using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))   (CONNECT_DATA=(sid=xe)))';
```

I am getting error "Insufficient privileges".
Please help me out.

Comment: Did you mean created two users? Instead of databases? If so check that whether the user create database link has the `CREATE DATABASE LINK`  system privilege and the connecting user has `CREATE SESSION` system privilege.

Answer (score 6):

It should be `CONNECT TO` username not the database name as shown in the following image which describes the syntax of `CREATE DATABASE LINK`. We define database instance/service under `USING connect_string` clause.

[image]

> #### Prerequisites
>
> To create a private database link, you must have the `CREATE DATABASE LINK` system privilege. To create a public database link, you must have the `CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK` system privilege. Also, you must have the `CREATE SESSION` system privilege on the remote Oracle database.

***Reference:***[CREATE DATABASE LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205)

***Demo***

```
[oracle@orcl Desktop]$ sqlplus system/oracle

SQL> create user abc identified by abc;

User created.

SQL> create user xyz identified by xyz;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to abc;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn abc/abc
Connected.

SQL> create database link testlink connect to pqr identified by pqr using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orcl.dba.com)(PORT=1522))   (CONNECT_DATA=(service=orcl)))';
create database link testlink connect to pqr identified by pqr using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orcl.dba.com)(PORT=1522))   (CONNECT_DATA=(service=orcl)))'
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> conn system/oracle
Connected.
SQL> grant create database link to abc;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create database link testlink connect to pqr identified by pqr using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orcl.dba.com)(PORT=1522))   (CONNECT_DATA=(service=orcl)))';^[[3~^C

SQL> conn abc/abc
Connected.
SQL> create database link testlink connect to pqr identified by pqr using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orcl.dba.com)(PORT=1522))   (CONNECT_DATA=(service=orcl)))';

Database link created.
```

Comment: yes when i try to execute grant create database link i get same error message. How Do I give system privilege?

Comment: Connect as `sys` user with `sysdba` privilege then try to grant the required privileges. For example: `sqlplus sys as sysdba` then `SQL> grant ...`

Comment: Here main issue is i cannot login as sys user also. I tried sys and sys and other combinations too.

Comment: @poonam: Then connect as `SYSTEM` user and grant `CREATE DATABASE LINK` to  `abc` user. Next, connect as `abc` user and create the database link. Refer to the demo.

Comment: Public database links are a security vulnerability. Use them with caution.